# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the header of CAS responce?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cas

I want to use CAS (Central Authentication Service) RESTful API from javascript in my HTML+javascript application. The main problem is cross-domain requests from jquery ajax, as the CAS server is on the other domain. I have buid CAS server from CAS overlay. Does anybody know how to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the header of CAS responce?